# How read list items in list using linq in C#?

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have the following class

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class R_ButterFly_Collection
{
        [DataMember]
        public Int64? CollectionNameID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string CollectionName { get; set; }
}
```

I need to read `CollectionNameID` and `CollectionName` for given match for `collection_name`.

This is how I tried for `CollectionName` :

```
string CollectionName = ButterFlyList.Where(x => x.CollectionName == butterflyName)
```

But I need `CollectionNameID` and `CollectionName`, how could I do that ?

This is what I want :

```
Int64 CollectionNameID, CollectionName = ButterFlyList.Where(x => x.CollectionName == butterflyName)
```

Comment: Look up LINQ's `Select`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming:

```
var ButterFlyList = new List<R_ButterFly_Collection>()
            {
                new R_ButterFly_Collection()
                {
                    CollectionName="one",
                    CollectionNameID=1
                },
                new R_ButterFly_Collection()
                {
                    CollectionName="two",
                    CollectionNameID=2
                },
                new R_ButterFly_Collection()
                {
                    CollectionName="three",
                    CollectionNameID=3
                }
            };
```

Then you can use linq and return tuple result:

```
var results = ButterFlyList.Where(x => x.CollectionName == "one").Select(p => new Tuple<long, string>(p.CollectionNameID ?? 0, p.CollectionName));
```

Note that you need to handle nullable long for CollectionNameID field.

Comment: This is what I wanted, thank you. How do you read the result > results.Item1 does not work here

Comment: Well, since I used where it will return IEnumerable so you need to get that first. Example: var first = results.FirstOrDefault()?.Item1;
            var second = results.FirstOrDefault()?.Item2;

Answer (score 2):

you can use :

```
 List<R_ButterFly_Collection> results = ButterFlyList.Where(x => x.CollectionName == butterflyName).ToList();
```